# An example of two elements without a greatest common divisor

Tags: examples, ac.commutative-algebra

Is there an easy example of an integral domain and two elements on it which do not have a greatest common divisor?  It will have to be a non-UFD, obviously.

"Easy" means that I can explain it to my undergrad students, although I will be happy with any example.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Here's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) an example stolen blatantly from wikipedia.

Let $R=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]$, let $a=4=2*2=(1+\sqrt{-3})(1-\sqrt{-3})$ and $b=2(1+\sqrt{-3})$.  Now, $2$ and $1+\sqrt{-3}$ are both maximal among divisors, but are not associates, thus, there is not GCD.

Comment: More generally, GCD domains are integrally closed.  (Note that the real problem here is not about two elements, but one: the lattice of divisors of 4 does not have suprema.)

Comment: Thanks.  I should learn to look up wikipedia before asking.

Answer (score 8):

I should point out, there are plenty of examples in integrally closed rings. For example:

In $k[a,b,c,d]/(ad-bc)$, there is no GCD of $ad$ and $ab$. (Note that $a$ and $b$ are both common divisors.)

In $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$, there is no GCD of $6$ and $2 (1+\sqrt{-5})$. (Note that $2$ and $1+\sqrt{-5}$ are both common divisors.)

Answer (score 6):

It deserves to be much better known that **nonexistant GCDs** (and, similarly, **nonprincipal ideals**)
arise *immediately* from any failure of Euclid's Lemma, and this provides an illuminating way to view many of the standard examples. Below is a detailed explanation extracted from one of my sci.math.research posts [2]. The results below hold true in *any* domain D.

**LEMMA**:  (a,b) = (ac,bc)/c  if  (ac,bc)  exists

Proof: d|a,b <=> dc|ac,bc <=> dc|(ac,bc) <=> d|(ac,bc)/c. QED

**EUCLID'S LEMMA**:  a|bc and (a,b)=1 => a|c, if (ac,bc) exists

Proof:   a|ac,bc => a|(ac,bc) = (a,b)c = c  via Lemma. QED

Therefore if a,b,c fail to satisfy the implication in Euclid's Lemma,
namely  if  (a,b) = 1  and  a|bc, not a|c, then one
immediately deduces that the gcd (ac,bc) fails to exist in D.

E.g. David Speyer's example above, and Khurana's example in [1] (= Theorem 41 in Pete L. Clark's [0]) are simply specializations where  a,b,c = p,1+w,1-w  in a quadratic number (sub)ring Z[w], ww = -d.

[0] Clark, Pete. L. Factorization in integral domains. 29pp. 2010.
[http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~pete/factorization2010.pdf](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/factorization2010.pdf)

[1] D. Khurana, On GCD and LCM in domains: A Conjecture of Gauss.
Resonance 8 (2003), 72-79.
https://www.ias.ac.in/article/fulltext/reso/008/06/0072-0079

[2] sci.math.research, 3/12/09, seeking comments on expository article on factorization
http://groups.google.com/group/sci.math.research/msg/88343de90a4cf6b7
http://google.com/groups?selm=gparte%24si4%241%40dizzy.math.ohio-state.edu

Comment: Link [1] appears to be inoperative.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Updated the link.

Comment: @darij, didn't work for me, but https://www.ias.ac.in/article/fulltext/reso/008/06/0072-0079 got me there.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: OOps -- I misread "Link [1]" as "Link [0]" (which was inoperative, too) and fixed that one!

Answer (score 5):

Since Charles has already given you an example, I'll just mention that there is a name for integral domains in which any two non-zero elements have a gcd: [GCD-Domains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GCD_domain).

See also Pete's response to [“Counter”-example for Gauss’s Lemma on irreducible polynomials](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/6651/counter-example-for-gausss-lemma-on-irreducible-polynomials).

Comment: I'd actually never heard of GCD-domains and GL-domains until this question, partly because I had missed that thread.  Thanks Ben!

Comment: Right, and in the Noetherian case a GCD-domain is precisely a UFD.  So there are lots of examples.  

Answer (score 2):

Another possible answer, following Qiaochu's comment: The elements <strike>$x^2$ and $x^3$</strike> (**Edit:** $x^5$ and $x^6$) in $k[x^2, x^3]$ (alternatively, $k[x,y]/(x^3-y^2)$), where $k$ is a nonzero ring.

Comment: Non-integrally closed rings make my head spin, but don't those two elements have gcd 1?  (I can't find any non-constant common divisors).

I think x^4 and x^5 should work here, though.